# Merge TAG + synonym : sites and sites.com

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

EDIT: With your comments:

There will be the following synonyms:

two tags:

1. [force.com-sites](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force.com-sites)
2. [site.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site.com)

The questions tagged as: [sites](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sites) should be retagged accordingly

The [sites](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sites) will be blocked for usage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd argue that force.com sites and site.com are two very different but similarly named technologies. I think more appropriate would be force.com-sites (merging in sites) and site.com tags. Blacklisting "sites" as a general term would probably be a good idea in this situation.

For example: I have extensive experience with force.com sites but I've never so much as seen a site.com page, and the technology used to build them is again drastically different.

Comment: Agreed, these two are distinct.

Comment: I agree, I edited the q as to how the tags might be